# SignalR what happens if user is inactive?

Tags: signalr

I would like to know what will happen if the user is inactive.

Imagine user connected to the hub, the connection is established, but user doesn't refresh the page or doesn't do anything for an hour ... will the connection be maintained anyway?

And after that time can the message be pushed to him?

Comment: My experience is that in theory the answer is yes. In practice I have ran into issues like Windows going into Sleep mode that prevent SignalR from properly reconnecting. I am not sure that I didn't do something wrong to cause that behavior and I was using a beta version back then.

Comment: For me the issue was when a user navigates away from the application like closing the tab. I have disconnect() in client but that does not get called if tab is closed. So the key for me is to remove the connection from the server when the OnDisconnect eventually gets called.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

SignalR sends keep-alive messages which will keep the connection open even if there is no other activity (except for long-polling connections; in that case, the client will make its regular ajax requests which has the same effect of keeping the connection alive). So you'll be able to send a message after an hour of inactivity, for example.

If the client device goes into sleep mode or can't send those keep-alive messages for any other reason, then the connection will eventually be removed (you can determine the timeout via `GlobalHost.Configuration.DisconnectTimeout`). Take a look at the [documentation](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) for a more detailed explanation.

Comment: Oh one more thing this keep alive messages generate a lot of traffic and use cpu? Having 1000 ppl in this kind of inactive state but still on website ... might cause issue?

Comment: "a lot" is relative, but 1000 connections shouldn't be a problem for the average server